# Undefined response from axios action creator

Tags: typescript, redux, axios

I am refactoring my action creator and ran into an error. Basically, this action is sending a "get" request, which should retrieve a message and a status code (for now I try to get at least the message). In the browser, when I open the Network tab, the request has been sent, however my console log returns undefined. Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Here is the action creator itself:

```
export const handleFetchData =
  (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string) => async (dispatch: Function) => {
    try {
      const response = await mainApiProtected.mePage({});
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
};
```

And here are supporting TypeScript files:

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import HttpClientProtected from "./HttpClientProtected";

class MainProtected extends HttpClientProtected {
  private static instanceCached: MainProtected;

  private constructor() {
    super("http://142.93.134.108:1111/");
  }

  static getInstance = () => {
    if (!MainProtected.instanceCached) {
      MainProtected.instanceCached = new MainProtected();
    }

    return MainProtected.instanceCached;
  };

  public mePage = (body: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    this.instance.get<{ message: string }>("/me", body);
  };
}

export default MainProtected;
```

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import HttpClient from "./HttpClient";

abstract class HttpClientProtected extends HttpClient {
  constructor(baseURL: string) {
    super(baseURL);

    this.initializeRequestInterceptors();
  }

  private initializeRequestInterceptors = () => {
    this.instance.interceptors.request.use(this.handleMe);
    this.instance.interceptors.response.use(this.handleMeResponse);
  };

  private handleMe = (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    const updatedConfig = config;
    updatedConfig.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    return updatedConfig;
  };

  private handleMeResponse = ({ data }: AxiosResponse) => data;
}

export default HttpClientProtected;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like your `mePage` is actually returning a Promise or anything:

```js
  public mePage = (body: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    this.instance.get<{ message: string }>("/me", body);
  };
```

You probably meant to add a `return` there, or remove the `{ }` brackets for an implicit return.